# Proxy Server options for school administrators

Tags: network, proxy, http-proxy

I want to set up a proxy server for a school to prevent users to log-in to site like Facebook, Youtube, etc.

I have no idea how to do this, so I´d really appreciate your help.

Comment: Google for "phpproxy",  and then never ask anything like this on security.se again.  I am voting to close this question.

Comment: @ION Are you asking how to set up a proxy in order to block Facebook, or do you want to get past a block on Facebook at school?

Comment: @schroeder Yeah, i just want the proxy for block pages like that.

Comment: @Rook excuse the inconvenience.

Answer (score 5):

It may be easier for you all to use a DNS service such as OpenDNS where you can block based on hostnames and/or web categories. This will be a lot easier to setup and maintain if you are not very familiar with IT. Here is the direct link to their web content filtering - https://www.opendns.com/web-filtering

Comment: +1 This is the right answer for 'rookies' who want to set up a proxy to block certain types of sites. I have clients who use this service.

Comment: tyvm guys.. i´ll be working on it =)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into a proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) which can do what you're describing with relatively little set up.

Squid is well documented and heavily used, so it would be a good solution for anybody in either a development phase or in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like [untangle](http://www.untangle.com/store/education-premium-conf.html)  It will give you what you are looking for, and there are a bunch of bolt on features that you can use in addition to web content filtering (which is one of the things you are trying to do).